# MassTransit Saga Automatonymous with EF Core persistence does not save the state into the database

Tags: entity-framework-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am learning to implement the Saga with MassTransit by using the EF Core as the persistence. I have followed an example in Youtube:

[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTI4FF7VogU)

[medium link](https://blog.stackademic.com/implementation-of-saga-orchestration-using-masstransit-dd238530f0d7)

Everything is working fine, the message can be processed correctly by all the services, except the state does not save the data into the database table. I have applied migration script and the `TicketStateData` table is successfully created in the database.

However there is no data inserted from after the first event is triggered to the end of the event. What setting or configuration am I missing here?

The code - Saga:

```
public class TicketStateData : SagaStateMachineInstance
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }
    public DateTime TicketCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TicketCancelDate { get; set; }
    public Guid TicketId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
}

public class TicketStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<TicketStateData>
{
    // 4 states are going to happen
    public State AddTicket { get; private set; }
    public State CancelTicket { get; private set; }
    public State CancelSendEmail { get; private set; }
    public State SendEmail { get; private set; }

    // 4 events are going to happen
    public Event<IAddTicketEvent> AddTicketEvent { get; private set; }
    public Event<ICancelGenerateTicketEvent> CancelGenerateTicketEvent { get; private set; }
    public Event<ICancelSendEmailEvent> CancelSendEmailEvent { get; private set; }
    public Event<ISendEmailEvent> SendEmailEvent { get; private set; }

    public TicketStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(s => s.CurrentState);
        Event(() => AddTicketEvent, a => a.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.TicketId));
        Event(() => CancelGenerateTicketEvent, a => a.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.TicketId));
        Event(() => CancelSendEmailEvent, a => a.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.TicketId));
        Event(() => SendEmailEvent, a => a.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.TicketId));

        // A message comming from ticket service 
        // it could be the initially state
        Initially(
            When(AddTicketEvent).Then(context =>
            {
                context.Saga.TicketId = context.Message.TicketId;
                context.Saga.Title = context.Message.Title;
                context.Saga.Email = context.Message.Email;
                context.Saga.TicketNumber = context.Message.TicketNumber;
                context.Saga.Age = context.Message.Age;
                context.Saga.Location = context.Message.Location;
            }).TransitionTo(AddTicket).Publish(context => new                       GenerateTicketEvent(context.Saga)));
        // During AddTicketEvent some other events might occured 
        During(AddTicket,
           When(SendEmailEvent)
           .Then(context =>
           {
               // These values could be different 
               context.Saga.TicketId = context.Message.TicketId;
               context.Saga.Title = context.Message.Title;
               context.Saga.Email = context.Message.Email;
               context.Saga.TicketNumber = context.Message.TicketNumber;
               context.Saga.Age = context.Message.Age;
               context.Saga.Location = context.Message.Location;
           }).TransitionTo(SendEmail));
        During(AddTicket,
           When(CancelGenerateTicketEvent)
           .Then(context =>
           {
               // These values could be different 
               context.Saga.TicketId = context.Message.TicketId;
               context.Saga.Title = context.Message.Title;
               context.Saga.Email = context.Message.Email;
               context.Saga.TicketNumber = context.Message.TicketNumber;
               context.Saga.Age = context.Message.Age;
               context.Saga.Location = context.Message.Location;
           }).TransitionTo(CancelTicket));
        // During SendEmailEvent some other events might occured 
        During(SendEmail,
             When(CancelSendEmailEvent)
             .Then(context =>
             {
                 // These values could be different 
                 context.Saga.TicketId = context.Message.TicketId;
                 context.Saga.Title = context.Message.Title;
                 context.Saga.Email = context.Message.Email;
                 context.Saga.TicketNumber = context.Message.TicketNumber;
                 context.Saga.Age = context.Message.Age;
                 context.Saga.Location = context.Message.Location;
             }).TransitionTo(CancelSendEmail));
    }
}
```

`AppDbContext`:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TicketStateData>().HasKey(x => x.CorrelationId);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<TicketStateData> TicketStateData { get; set; }
}
```

`Program.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");

// Register SagaContext
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(db => db.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddBus(provider => MessageBrokers.RabbitMQ.ConfigureBus(provider));
    cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<TicketStateMachine, TicketStateData>()
        .EntityFrameworkRepository(r =>
        {
            r.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Pessimistic; // or use Optimistic, which requires RowVersion

            r.ExistingDbContext<AppDbContext>();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image: table in database]

If you want to see the source code for whole project, the author has upload at
[github](https://github.com/Vahidalizadeh7070/SagaStateMachine_Medium)

I have checked the documentation on the MassTransit website, but I am not sure which part is missing. Appreciate if anyone can help me.